# Edit opened HTML Page, with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon, add-on

I was looking into making Firefox addons, and I need some help.
Is it possible to edit an HTML page that is open in the browser with javascript?
For example:

- User types in "google.com"
- Addon is activated
- Javascript changes contents of "google.com" to maybe say "Hello!" at the bottom.

Of course this isn't specifically what I want to do, but a push in the right direction on how to accomplish such a task would be great.
~Carpetfizz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within a Firefox addon this is obviously possible as many extensions do this.

If you, however, simply want to modify the DOM and nothing else than I would recommend taking a look at greasemonkey. Loads of example scripts around to do this: http://userscripts.org/

And the added benefit, if written correctly they also work in Chrome and other browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've read so far that DOM can create webpages, but I am unable to find out how to edit an html page that is currently loaded into that browser instance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. You must find a tutorial about javascript DOM manipulation